# How to pronounce "commenter"

Tags: pronunciation

What is the pronunciation of the word "commenter" from the word "comment"? I would like to know where the word stress is.

You could use [this IPA keyboard](http://ipa.typeit.org/) or upload a recorded copy of your voice online on [Forvo.](http://www.forvo.com/)

Comment: *Commenter* is the same as the word *comment* but, with an extra *er* sound on the end. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/comment_1?q=comment

Comment: [here](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=commenter&submit=Submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stress is on the first syllable, just like it is in *comment*. Emphatically it "rhymes" with *integer* or *manager*. [This recording is correct](http://www.forvo.com/search/commenter/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Pronounce it in the same way as *presenter* (`/prɪˈzɛntə/`):

> /ˈkɒmɛntə/

While correct, it is not a commonly used word. Other more common synonyms are commentator, critic or observer.

Comment: If you notice, it doesn't rhyme with **presenter** because the stress (which is my main concern) in **presenter** is on the second syllable while the stress in **commenter** is on the first syllable, and this difference is quite important in pronunciation. As for word choice, when you come across, you should know how a word is pronounced. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I take it from your frontal stress and "ɒ" sound that your pronunciation is US English?

Comment: @learner This answer gives a BrE pronunciation, but an AmE pronunciation would stress the same syllable.

Comment: Your right, I was mistaken by the "ɒ" sound for "ɑ". It's the one facing left! Also it's a long sound "ɑː" as shown in Cambridge's Advanced learner's dictionary. I pronounced it right but took it written in the wrong way. Thanks for the correction, much appreciated.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. The question explicitly asks about which syllable is stressed and they have different stresses. Also "commenter" is used fairly often online and is **not** a synonym for commentator, critic or observer. (And I don't think observer is a synonym for the other two anyway.)